# Install OpenCV in Google colaboratory for c++ takes too many time

Tags: c++, opencv, google-colaboratory

I am programming in c ++ using OpenCV. In google Colaboratory I have to install it every time I start working. It is slow and time consuming to build and install.
Is there a way to do it fast? Is OpenCV not pre-installed in Google Colaboratory?
Thanks you

I'm following these steps to install OpenCV.

```
!apt-get install build-essential
!apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
!apt-get install python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libdc1394-22-dev

!cd /content/
!git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
!git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git

!mkdir /content/opencv/build
%cd /content/opencv/build
#!cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/content/opencv_contrib/modules -DWITH_CUDA=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DBUILD_DOCS=TRUE -DBUIL_EXAMPLES=TRUE -DENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -DCUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -DWITH_CUBLAS=1 ..
! time cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/content/opencv_contrib/modules -DWITH_CUDA=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DBUILD_DOCS=FALSE -DBUIL_EXAMPLES=FALSE ..

! time make -j2
%cd /content/opencv/build
!time make install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know you could run c++ code in Google Colab: not expert, but hope I can provide some useful suggestions.

It seems that OpenCV 3.2 is already installed on Colab:

```
!find .. -name 'libopencv*'
```

outputs:

```
../usr/share/lintian/overrides/libopencv3.2-jni
../usr/share/lintian/overrides/libopencv-contrib3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-objdetect3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-calib3d3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-videoio3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-features2d3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-flann-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-video3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-videoio-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-imgproc3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-contrib-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-objdetect-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-imgcodecs3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv3.2-java
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-superres3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-stitching-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv3.2-jni
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-core3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-core-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-superres-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-features2d-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-ml3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-viz-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-calib3d-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-highgui-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-highgui3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-flann3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-video-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-imgproc-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-videostab-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-photo3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-shape-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-ts-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-viz3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-stitching3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-ml-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-imgcodecs-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-videostab3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-shape3.2
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-photo-dev
../usr/share/doc/libopencv-contrib3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_optflow.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_datasets.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_line_descriptor.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_xphoto.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_hdf.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_line_descriptor.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_shape.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_face.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_text.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_aruco.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_xphoto.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_dpm.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_hdf.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_dpm.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_plot.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_plot.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videoio.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_bioinspired.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_viz.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_rgbd.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_reg.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_viz.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_shape.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_text.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_optflow.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ccalib.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_saliency.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_bgsegm.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_line_descriptor.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_face.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_surface_matching.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_face.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_xobjdetect.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_bioinspired.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_saliency.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_viz.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_rgbd.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_plot.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_structured_light.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_text.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_saliency.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ccalib.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_xphoto.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_structured_light.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_reg.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_optflow.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_fuzzy.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_saliency.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_dpm.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_freetype.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videoio.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_shape.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_aruco.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_reg.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ximgproc.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ximgproc.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_bioinspired.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ximgproc.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_fuzzy.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_bgsegm.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_optflow.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_plot.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ccalib.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_xobjdetect.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_freetype.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_surface_matching.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_hdf.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_freetype.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_xobjdetect.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_reg.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_xphoto.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stereo.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_aruco.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_shape.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_structured_light.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_freetype.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_rgbd.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_hdf.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_text.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_bgsegm.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgcodecs.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_bgsegm.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_bioinspired.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_structured_light.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videoio.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_surface_matching.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_dpm.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_xobjdetect.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_aruco.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ximgproc.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_fuzzy.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stereo.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_face.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ccalib.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_datasets.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stereo.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_rgbd.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stereo.so
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_datasets.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_line_descriptor.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_fuzzy.a
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_viz.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_datasets.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videoio.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_surface_matching.so.3.2
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so.3.2.0
../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.3.2
```

There's also:

```
../usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake
```

and `!pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
outputs:

```
-I/usr/include/opencv -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_video -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_viz -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_text -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
```

Alternatively, if you want to use OpenCV 4.4 you could either look for different apt-get mirrors that might have it or compile on a 64-bit Ubuntu (physical or virtual machine) and have the install folder as a ready to download `.tar.gz` archive or something.
Bare in mind if you use CMake you can point to `install/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake`(without having to replace the `/usr/lib` files)

This is the version info I get on a CPU only Colab:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Works. 

I use the OpenCVConfig.cmake to make my CPP project in this way:

`!cmake -D OpenCV_DIR=/usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake ..`